# Custom Sorting Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection that I want to sort into groups based on type and then display to an html table.

The values I want to sort by are not in alphabetical order.  Let's say:

```
var Animals = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            animal_name: '',
            species: '',
            food_preference: '',
            characteristics: [],
        },

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('Animal being created...');
        }

    });
```

I want to sort by food_preference.  Note that food_preference can only assume 3 values: carnivore, herbivore, and omnivore.

I want to display all Animals that are omnivores on the table first, then carnivores, then herbivores.  Since any regular sorting functionality would display carnivores first because it's alphabetical, this won't work.

What is the most intuitive way to sort the backbone collection with these custom features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide a custom [`comparator`](https://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) method that returns a number according to the order you wish to set:

```
var AnimalsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: function(m) {
        switch (m.get('food_preference')) {
            case 'omnivores': return 1;
            case 'carnivore': return 2;
            case 'herbivores': return 3;
            default: return Infinity;
        }
    }
});
```

And a demo

```js
var c = new Backbone.Collection([
    {animal_name: 3, food_preference: 'herbivores'},
    {animal_name: 2, food_preference: 'carnivore'},
    {animal_name: 1, food_preference: 'omnivores'},
    {animal_name: 4}
]);

console.log(c.pluck('animal_name'));

c.comparator = function(m) {
    switch (m.get('food_preference')) {
        case 'omnivores': return 1;
        case 'carnivore': return 2;
        case 'herbivores': return 3;
        default: return Infinity;
    }
};
c.sort();
console.log(c.pluck('animal_name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks a lot!